# how make checkbox stay checked and reset in node js

Tags: node.js

I am working on a small project with checkbox and node js. I need the checked box stay on the screen after I click submit button and reset the form after clicking reset button.How can do that?

ejs code

```
<form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="checkbox" name="preference" value="A">A
    <input type="checkbox" name="preference" value="B">B
    <input type="checkbox" name="preference" value="C">C
    <input type="submit" value="Click to Submit">
    <input type="reset" value="Erase and Restart">
</form>
```

node js

```
express.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('form');
});

express.post('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  let checkedValue =req.body.preference;
  let output = checkedValue==undefined?`You didn' make selection.`:`The preference iterm on menu is ${checkedValue}`;
  res.render('form',{
    output:output,
  });
    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What's going on is that when you submit your form, the webpage is reloaded, so you lose your checked state. You can either save the values on your server and have them pre-checked using an optional checked flag in your ejs template or you can add some client side javascript to handle the form submission for you by writing and event handler for the submit event on the form.

if you expand your ejs template with a conditional `checked` value on your inputs, your returned page will have them pre-checked

```
<input type="checkbox" name="preference" <% if (submittedValue === "A") { %>checked<% } %> value="A">A
```

Or, here's a super simple bit of javascript that would send the values to your server

```
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the form from submitting with a page refresh
  const data = { values: [] };
  e.target.elements.forEach((formEl) => {
    if (formEl.checked) data.values.push(formEl.value);
  });
  
  fetch('/urlToProcessYourForm', { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(data) });

});
```